# Post data from angular to php api side

Tags: php, angular, angular-forms

Here is my (login.service.ts) code:

```
private pageURL = 'http://localhost/social/src/app/api/ws/react_signup_login/login.php';
    user = new UserLogin();

    login(value: Object): Observable<any> {
        const body = new URLSearchParams();
        Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
            body.set(key, value[key]);
        });

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type',
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this._http.post(this.pageURL, this.user.toString(), {
            headers: headers
        }).map(res => res.json());
    }
```

And this is my login.ts class

```
export class UserLogin {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

in (login.component.ts)

```
user = new UserLogin();
login(value) {
        this._loginService.login({value})
            .subscribe(
                response => this.user = response,
                error => console.log(error)
            );
    }
```

Finally my (login.php) that I expect the error is here

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-type:application/json");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST))
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$params['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$params['password'] = $_POST['password'];
```

When I'm trying to (var_dump) the `$params` I got this:

```
array(2) {
  ["username"]=>
  NULL
  ["password"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: Can you first of all check in your browser network and see if you are sending Good data. Maybe you are not sending correct data to your API. Also make a simple `var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true))`

Comment: what is the content of `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your POST Http call you should use your defined URLSearchParams as body and not user, because your user object is empty.

Change your http call code block in `login.service.ts` from this:

```
return this._http.post(this.pageURL, this.user.toString(), {
            headers: headers
        }).map(res => res.json());
```

to this:

```
return this._http.post(this.pageURL, body.toString(), {
            headers: headers
        }).map(res => res.json());
```

Comment: @YazanMehrez Have tried to use ``body.append(key, value[key]);`` instead of ``body.set(key, value[key]);`` ?

Comment: @YazanMehrez Can you add ``console.log(body)`` before ``let headers = new Headers()`` and post the output from console.log here?

Comment: @YazanMehrez Is your import of ``URLSearchParams`` is correct? It should be imported from e.g. ``@angular/http``

Comment: The wrong was in URLSearchParams import, thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

```
return this._http.post(this.pageURL, value, {
        headers: headers
    }).map(res => res.json());
```

Where value is your user object